# Reference characters found in replace all with regex

Tags: java, regex, string

My goal is to introduce a space between capital letters in an upper camel case formatted string. 
e.g. *ThisIsATest -> This Is A Test*.

Currently I do this by calling this function

```
public static String addSpacesBetweenCapitalLetters(String input) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for(char c : input.toCharArray()) {
        sb.append(Character.isUpperCase(c) ? " "+c : c);
    }

    if(sb.codePointAt(0)==new Character(' ')) {
        sb.deleteCharAt(0);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

I am wondering if there is also a way to use String.replaceAll(regex,replacement) to solve this task. Capital leters can be found by using regex easily. Can we reference the found character in the replacement similar to the following code?

```
input.replaceAll("[A-Z]"," "+&foundChar);
```

Comment: As is said in the programming world, when you have an algorithm, you have a problem to solve. When you have an algorithm that uses a regex, you have two problems to solve.

Comment: Your original program is easy to understand and maintain. A regex solution (see answer) needs intensive study to find out what it does.

Comment: @Henry For this problem it might be easy but I would like to know if it's possible for possible future tasks. I'll never excited if I have to use regex but maybe it comes in handy sometimes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this [regex based on lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
str = str.replaceAll("(?<=\\p{L})(?=\\p{Lu})", " ");
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Bopppd/1)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `(?<=\p{L})`: Lookbehind to assert that we have any case letter at previous position
- `(?=\p{Lu})`: Lookahead to assert that we have an uppercase letter at next position

Comment: That was quick thank you. I wasn't aware of lookarounds, in fact I have never even heard about them. As hoped something new learnt today :-).

Comment: @John: Please check this excellent tutorial on look arounds: https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html